# Font of page title appears different on browsers in Windows and on Linux

Tags: css, wordpress

On my wordpress blog, the page title appears differently in windows and on linux. On Linux in Firefox its smooth and appears as it should,but on Windows in both Firefox and IE it has rough edges. On Windows, it appears http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/4592/picwindows.png . Any way to fix this ?

The CSS is as follows :

```
#pagetitle{
  padding: 3em 0 0 1em;
}

#pagetitle h1.logo{
  font-family: "Arial Black", Arial, Helvetica, Sans, FreeSans, Jamrul, Garuda, Kalimati;
  font-size: 500%;
  float: left;
  padding: .1em 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.1em;
  /*font-variant: small-caps;*/ /* Uncomment this line to change title to uppercase */
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #eeeadb;
}

#pagetitle h1.logo a{
  color: #eeeadb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#pagetitle h1.logo a:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

#pagetitle h4{
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #8e7762;
  padding: .6em 0 .6em .8em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: #e9e2c9;
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on cleartype, in your desktop settings?